# Get directories & files of a theme in module

Tags: 7, files

How can I scan a directory and its files from a module? Is there any permission issue?
I have to apply some logic based on the folder structure in the active theme.

When I use the below code, its returning empty

```
file_scan_directory($path,$depth=0);
```

I am getting the path to theme by below code:

```
$path = base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme','sandesh').'/'.'layouts';
```

Is this the wrong method to this? Or is there any other apis for that.

Comment: I have also tried using scandir php function instead of file_scan_directory . That is showing error .

Comment: Just a hint: Have a look how drupal core or other contrib modules doing it. Check drupal_get_path or module_invoke_all are finding their files. The variables module is also looking for *.variable.inc files in module directories. I often learn from other modules how to do things.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing filesystem path and URL path:

- [`base_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/base_path/7): Returns the base **URL** path (i.e., directory)
  of the Drupal installation.
- [`drupal_get_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7): Returns the path to a system item (module, theme, etc.).

The second argument for [`file_scan_directory()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_scan_directory/7) is the [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) regular expression of the files to find. You are using '0' which only match a single file named '0'.

`file_scan_directory(DRUPAL_ROOT  . '/' . drupal_get_path('theme','sandesh') . '/' . 'layouts');` is all you need to do. Use `base_path()` only when building URL for which an existing helper function ([`url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7), [`file_create_url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7), etc.) cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem has to do with using web paths instead of filesystem paths.

[`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) will have the path that your sites is stored in on the server, eg /var/www/html.  You should then be able to concatenate this with the results from [`drupal_get_path`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7) to get the read directory.  You will likely need to play with adding / at places in the path.

You may also be able to use [`DRUPAL_ROOT`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/index.php/constant/DRUPAL_ROOT/7) instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, but I don't quite recall if they are always equivalent.  You could also potentially use [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) from within the theme or module.

Comment: I tried using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and printed the path , the result is 'D:/xampp/htdocs/sites/all/themes/sandesh/layouts/dir', but still 'scandir($path)' shows error and returns false value .